# Why is the SO logo in the new accounts tab darker than the original one?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, logo

A few days ago I noticed that the [accounts tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/143169/marcel-korpel?tab=accounts) is restyled (which made it clearer, by the way). However, the Stack Overflow logo shown there is darker than the original one on Stack Overflow:

[image: left: original logo, right: logo in accounts tab]

Is this done on purpose? It just seemed to me that the right logo referred to another SE site, not Stack Overflow itself.

<sub>([Don't Make Me Think!](http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html))</sub>

Comment: It's not just darker, it's redder; the hue has been changed on that small version. The top box on the 'real' icon is HSV(28,96,100) while the top box on the small icon is HSV(358,87,96); it's so red, it's wrapped around on its way to magenta!

Comment: When you shrink things they get 'stronger', or more 'concentrated'.  For example, imagine leaving a hamster out in the sun, after a while the hamster shrinks a bit and therefore becomes 'more hamster'.  Same thing with logos, the excess water is lost, but all the colour is there so it gets stronger.

Comment: @Tom: Huh? I tried this before, but my hamster didn't become 'more hamster', it merely dried out and got very thirsty afterwards. It also depend on the kind of pigments whether or not colours will get stronger when exposing them to sunlight; some will even fade. Moreover, a normal image editor will interpolate colours, not make them stronger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That image is a scale down of our [Apple Touch Icon](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), which was a tad out of date w.r.t. logo colors.

A [new image](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) has been pushed out, and will eventually force the old image out of cache everywhere.